# The Label is missing Error eclipse

Tags: java, continue

I have this code and basically my problem is that i want to return to my while loop. I tried continue for the first time but i it does not work..

```
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Did Not Choose Between Keep Or Execute..Program Exiting","Error Nothing Chosed",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    continue test;
                }
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An Error Occured, Please Restart The Game!","Winner Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                Attack=false;
                MainMenu=true;
            }
        }
} }
```

I tried returning at the code below but it does not work. So my question is how can i make this work with continue statement or with another statement.. Thank you

```
test: 
        {while(MainMenu){
    String M1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Name1+" you are starting first. Here are your options\n 1.Invade \n 2.Buy \n 3.Pass \n 4.Check Money Balance \n 5.Check Soldier Count \n 6.Citizen's Hapinness","Type the Number of the action you want to take place");
    if(M1.equals("1")){
        if(CityNum==1){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You are Currently At The Veiled Atoll so you have the option to invade \n 1.Zicat Penishula \n 2.Flehst Archipelago \n 3.The Sharktooth Isle","Type the Number of the Island you want to Invade");
        String CurrentIsland="The Veiled Atoll";
        MainMenu=false;
        Attack=true;
        }
```

Comment: your cording format is horrible

Comment: I know that.. I'm a learning java from videos so yeah I'm not giving so much effort on the format of my code

Comment: plz don't ignore code format .this will lead to lot of errors

Comment: @FastSnail What exactly do you mean by code format?

Comment: i'm trying .but i told you about format not to make you upset .but it's good thing you should do when you code

Comment: i mean code conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html

Comment: I tryed using MainMenu=false; MainMenu=true; to restart my while loop but it does not work the program ends

Comment: OOOH btw my code format is not like it shows there... I mean its not the best but its way better than above xD. It's just a paste error thats why it looks like that. Sry for that

Comment: can you post your entire code somewhere like pastebin .?

Comment: @FastSnail here you go http://pastebin.com/YXFGWRw2

Comment: your `test:` loop is not inside of `while (Attack) ` so you can't call `continue test;` you can only call it inside of test loop

Comment: @FastSnail but it is inside while(Attack)  you mean while(MainMenu)?

Comment: in your code they are not nested loops .wait i'm posting a snapshot

Comment: see http://i.imgur.com/qPdZaQj.png

Comment: @FastSnail Anw because my brain will blow soon xD. Do you have another way or a solution so it will work?

Comment: `while(MainMenu)` == `test` .so yes `test` is not visible to `while (Attack)`

Comment: @FastSnail So the solution is?

Comment: i can't understand the flow of your program since that's so much code.if you can show same problem in small code example i can help you. if you move 'attack loop' inside to 'mainmenu loop' you will not get a error .but i don't know is that you want or not

Comment: @FastSnail Ok listen as I said above the problem is there. Im looking for a way to reactivate my while(MainMenu) So the user can go back on the menu. Any ideas on how to make that possible? (It doesnt have to do with continue and labels..)

Comment: if you move 'attack loop' inside to 'mainmenu loop' you will not get a error  .check is it what you want .try to run and check do you get expected output or not .here nested loop modification- http://pastebin.com/yws8QmFn

Comment: @FastSnail OMG Thank you soooo much.. Yes that is exactly what i want to do. Thank you you are the best :)